# Putting a div under another div's background

Tags: css

Not sure if this is possible, but I have a div with a "border" background. Inside this div is another div that holds the content, and I want this div to appear under the border.

Is this possible to do with CSS?

Edit: Sorry for writing it in a hurry, let me try to explain more.

The parent div uses background-image like so:

```
background-image: url(images/SomeImage.png)
```

SomeImage.png is just a custom border that appears at the top of the div.

I have a child div inside this parent div, and I want it to appear beneath SomeImage.png. Is this possible?

Comment: under how? z-index stacking? or positioning so that the content div appears lower on the screen than the background div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the "background image" in another div and using negative margins. Sorry for the confusion but none of the other solutions worked for me.

Comment: I think we all didn't quite understand your question to begin with. Glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Yes its tricky to explain without images and I can find no suitable image.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="border-bg">
   <div id="content">
      Your content goes here
   </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
​#border-bg {
    background:url(images/border.png) no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
#border {
    z-index:10;
    position:relative;
}​
```

Make sure to add the `width` and `height` of border image.

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

[Check this for more info about z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 1):

it is possiple. try changing the opacity of the parent div. 
for example 
$("#childdiv").css({ opacity: 1.0 });
$("#parentdiv").css({ opacity: 0.75 });

Comment: write your styles as CSS not jQuery please.

Comment: you are right. I'm new in stackoverflow and I didn't notice the tag. by the way I don't know how to do this using CSS. I just use JQuery in my site

Comment: `#childdiv{opacity:1;}` and `#parentdiv{opacity:.75;}` respectively.
How did you learn jQuery before CSS even?

Comment: well, I do know CSS, but not in depth. I use JS or JQuery for such effects. thnx for your answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply inner shadow http://sublimeorange.com/css/css3-inner-shadow/ on the content div?

```
<div id="border-frame" style="padding: 10px; background-color: red">
<div id="content" style="padding: 10px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000; background-color:white"> 
this is some great text
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzbVG/

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there...
I'm using this to put a background image behind a login screen...

```
 <table align=center width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0    background="images/image.png" STYLE="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center">
 <tr>
 <td align=center valign=middle height="350" background="images/loginimage.png"  STYLE="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center">

 Content Here

 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```